# Python код в Docker. Ошибка cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, docker, moviepy, synology

Необходимо на NAS Synology выполнить скрипт который будет сжимать видео, изменять размер. На NAS установлен докер, запущен контейнер с Python и необходимыми библиотеками.
Но, при выполнении `clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip(filename)` выдает ошибку `cannot allocate memory`.
Данный скрипт на **Windows** в **Docker** работает нормально.
Понимаю что проблема в нехватки памяти, но как решить этот вопрос нет понимания.

Пока нет возможности проверить на сервере, но планирую попробовать создание контейнера с атрибутами `-m 1GB --memory-swap -1` Может это помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо ограничить оперативную память для Docker контейнера и включить использование подкачки. Контейнер запускать с атрибутами

`-m 1GB --memory-swap -1`